# Ordering/placement of empty facet when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following faceted plot, which plots 3 facets in a 2x2 arrangement. The empty facet is in the lower right.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(cyl), ncol = 2)
```

[image: 2x2 plot with 3 facets. Empty facet is in the lower-right corner.]

I want to instead produce a plot that has the empty facet in the top row, e.g. like below:

[image: 2x2 plot with 3 facets. Empty facet is in the upper-right corner.]

**Is there any way to do this without messing with grobs or gtable?**

Comment: You might be able to do this by adding a "blank" factor level for `cyl`. from `?facet_wrap`: `# To change the order in which the panels appear, change the levels
# of the underlying factor.
mpg$class2 <- reorder(mpg$class, mpg$displ)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`facet_wrap` has an option `as.table`. From the docs:

> If TRUE, the default, the facets are laid out like a table with highest values at the bottom-right. If FALSE, the facets are laid out like a plot with the highest value at the top-right.

If you set `as.table = F`, you'll get a blank space at the top right, but the panels are now in an awkward order; they'll be laid out like

```
8 (blank)
4    6
```

To get the order you want, do a little preprocessing.

If you reverse the factor levels, you get a layout

```
4 (blank)
8    6
```

The order boils down to bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right.

Depending on how you want them arranged, you might have to order the facet levels manually, unless in your full project there's some other logic you can put together. I've done it manually here with `forcats::relevel`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl) %>%
           forcats::fct_relevel("6", "8", "4")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl), ncol = 2, as.table = F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I actually tried using `as.table` but misread the documentation and thought the default was `FALSE`! So I tried `facet_wrap(~factor(cyl), ncol = 2, as.table = TRUE)` and of course saw no change.