# Controlling facet_wrap with an odd number of facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a facetted plot like this one:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(cyl, ncol=2)
```

It produces a graph with two plots in the top row, and one in the bottom.

[image]

What I would like instead is one plot in the top row and two in the bottom. Is there a straightforward way (using `facet_wrap`) to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447366/ordering-placement-of-empty-facet-when-using-facet-wrap

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!